# Audio not loading with pyinstaller onefile "[AudioSDL2 ] Unable to load"

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller onefile does not load audio, only the images. When I test pyinstaller without onefile the app works fine and if I do pyinstaller onefile and put the audio on the folder dist the app works as well.

I tested the "resource_path" too, but does not work.

error
[WARNING] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to load som/som.ogg: b'Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src'

The app works, but the sound does not load.

I have:
python 3.8.10

pyinstaller 5.6.2 pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.13

"kivy[base]" kivy_examples --no-binary kivy

Here's an example

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import os, sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path

from sound import *

'''def resource_path(relative_path):
        """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
        base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

resource_path('som/Bleeping-Demo.ogg')'''

class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Menu(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.sonoplastia = Sonoplastia()
        self.sonoplastia.sonoplastiaAstronautaGeral['menu'].volume = .5
        self.sonoplastia.sonoplastiaAstronautaGeral['menu'].loop = True
        self.sonoplastia.sonoplastiaAstronautaGeral['menu'].play()
    
class teste(App):
    def build(self):
        return Gerenciador()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    teste().run()
```

sound.py

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

class Sonoplastia():
    
    sonoplastiaAstronautaGeral = {'menu': SoundLoader.load('som/som.ogg')}
```

teste.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0

<Gerenciador>
    Menu:
        id: menu_screen
        name: 'menu'
    
<Menu>:
    id: menu
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 1
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    #rgba: 1, 1, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    source: 'imagens/background.png'
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
```

teste.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
('D:\\Daniel\\python\\kivy\\teste\\imagens\\', 'imagens'),
('D:\\Daniel\\python\\kivy\\teste\\som\\*.ogg', 'som'),
('D:\\Daniel\\python\\kivy\\teste\\*.py', '.'),
('D:\\Daniel\\python\\kivy\\teste\\*.kv', '.')]

a = Analysis(
    ['D:\\Daniel\\python\\kivy\\teste\\main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=added_files,
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    name='teste',
    debug=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

```
[19848] PyInstaller Bootloader 5.x
[19848] LOADER: executable is D:\Daniel\python\kivy\teste\exe\dist\teste.exe
[19848] LOADER: homepath is D:\Daniel\python\kivy\teste\exe\dist
[19848] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[19848] LOADER: archivename is D:\Daniel\python\kivy\teste\exe\dist\teste.exe
[19848] LOADER: Cookie found at offset 0x175D1FF
[19848] LOADER: Extracting binaries
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482 with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\PIL with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\core with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\core\audio with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\core\clipboard with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\core\image with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\core\text with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\core\window with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\graphics with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\lib with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\lib\gstplayer with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\pywin32_system32 with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\win32com with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\win32com\shell with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\certifi with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\parsers with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\parsers\rst with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\parsers\rst\include with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\html4css1 with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\html5_polyglot with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\latex2e with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\odf_odt with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\pep_html with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes\big-black with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes\big-white with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes\default with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes\medium-black with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes\medium-white with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes\small-black with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\docutils\writers\s5_html\themes\small-white with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\imagens with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\data with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\data\fonts with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\data\glsl with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\data\images with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\data\keyboards with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\data\logo with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\modules with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy_install\modules\__pycache__ with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: creating directory C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\som with security string: D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-22434768-3712754840-1110132281-1001)
[19848] LOADER: Executing self as child
[19848] LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482
[19848] LOADER: Setting up to run child
[19848] LOADER: Creating child process
[19848] LOADER: Waiting for child process to finish...
[8080] PyInstaller Bootloader 5.x
[8080] LOADER: executable is D:\Daniel\python\kivy\teste\exe\dist\teste.exe
[8080] LOADER: homepath is D:\Daniel\python\kivy\teste\exe\dist
[8080] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482
[8080] LOADER: archivename is D:\Daniel\python\kivy\teste\exe\dist\teste.exe
[8080] LOADER: Cookie found at offset 0x175D1FF
[8080] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482)
[8080] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[8080] LOADER: ucrtbase.dll found: C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\ucrtbase.dll
[8080] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\python38.dll
[8080] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[8080] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[8080] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482
[8080] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\base_library.zip;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\lib-dynload;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482
[8080] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[8080] LOADER: Initializing python
[8080] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[8080] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\base_library.zip;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\lib-dynload;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482
[8080] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[8080] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[8080] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[8080] LOADER: extracted struct
[8080] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for struct...
[8080] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_archive
[8080] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod01_archive...
[8080] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_importers
[8080] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod02_importers...
[8080] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_ctypes
[8080] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod03_ctypes...
[8080] LOADER: extracted pyimod04_pywin32
[8080] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod04_pywin32...
[8080] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[8080] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[8080] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_gstreamer.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_kivy.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_subprocess.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_inspect.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pywintypes.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pythoncom.py
[8080] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgutil.py
[8080] LOADER: Running main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\danie\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-01-06_34.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198482\kivy\__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\Daniel\python\kivy\teste\exe\dist\teste.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to load som/som.ogg: b'Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src'
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 27.20.100.9664'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 27.20.100.9664'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

I want the pyinstaller onefile to load audio.

Comment: When you create the one-dir distribution the *.ogg files are copied in the som-subdir of your executable ?

Comment: Yes, and when I create the onefile the files are copied to the _MEIPASS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is going to solve your problem or not, but you can fix the issue of the app not being able to find your `.ogg` file by changing the path in the `sound.py`:

```
import os
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

som_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'som\\som.ogg') 

class Sonoplastia():
    
    sonoplastiaAstronautaGeral = {'menu': SoundLoader.load(som_path)}
```